# How to Clear derivative definitions?

Tags: clear

I can't find a Clear or ClearAll command that gets rid of Derivative definitions I created.  this code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
gau[x_, v_] = (1/Sqrt[2*Pi*v])*E^-((x^2)/(2*v));
Derivative[0, n_][p][x, v] := Simplify[D[gau[z, v], {v, n}]];
ClearAll["Global`*"];
gau[x_, v_] = (1/Sqrt[2*Pi*v])*E^-((x^2)/(2*v));
Derivative[0, n_][p][x, v] := Simplify[D[gau[z, v], {v, n}]/gau[z, v]];
D[p[x, v], {v, 2}]
```

produces output consistent with the 1st definition, not the second.

Comment: related [mathematica-clear-a-functions-derivative-definition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454887/mathematica-clear-a-functions-derivative-definition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you most likely want to define your functions with patterns `x_, y_` instead of fixed symbols `x, y`. Second, you can use [`Unset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Unset.html) to achieve what (I think) you want. This is needed because `Derivative` is not in the `Global` context, but instead in the `System` context. So your `ClearAll` command doesn't affect it. But you also don't want to just say `ClearAll[Derivative]` because that may remove definitions you still need. `Unset` is more specific. You use it as follows:

```
Derivative[0,n_][p][x_,v_]=.
```

This can still be combined with the `ClearAll["Global*"];` that you already had, to make sure other definitions are removed.

Comment: Will ClearAll[Derivative] only clear the derivs that I defined?  Or will it mess up MMa built-in functions?

Comment: Since Derivative is not protected, `ClearAll[Derivative]` would indeed affect its properties. E.g., I checked `SubValues[Derivative]` before and after, and there is a difference...

Comment: Is the reason you recommend patterns here incase he tries to find a function with different variable names (than x,v)?